# Why nested for matrix iteration with explicit indices (javascript-like) in Python causes IndexError?

Tags: python-3.x

I need the equivalent of this javascript code:

```
var a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]];
var b = [[6,8,3],[0,9,6],[1,8,4],[5,1,3]];
var r = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]];
var rows=4;
var cols=3;
for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            r[i][j] += a[i][j] * b[j][i];
        }
}
```

So I have created this Python code:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
b = [[6,8,3],[0,9,6],[1,8,4],[5,1,3]]
r = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
rows=4
cols=3
for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            r[i][j] += a[i][j] * b[j][i]
```

but unfortunately in Python seems this approach doesn't work and my code crashes with  `IndexError: list index out of range` 
in the line

```
r[i][j] += a[i][j] * b[j][i]
```

Why this happens?

Comment: Your _JS_ code doesn't work. You wind up with the last row of r being NaNs, for precisely the same reason your Python code fails: you're referring to cells which don't exist.  What're you trying to do?

Comment: @DSM matrix scalar product

Comment: Eh?  A matrix scalar product would be multiplying every element of the matrix by the same scalar, which can't be what you're doing because you're trying to flip two matrices.  You can't be doing a matrix multiplication because your dimensions are wrong (you can't multiply 4x3 by 4x3, only 4x3 by 3x4).  And you can't be doing a Hadamard (elementwise) multiplication because you said that @user3505494 was wrong, and you claim your JS code works.

Comment: *scalar dot product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it happens because you write `b[j][i]`, but correct `b[i][j]`.